# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.' in C# - a GraphQL Client

Tags: c#, exception, graphql, client

I am working on a generic GraphQL Client without any static type.

But my problem at first is that I get the exception from
GraphQL.Client.Newtonsoft...
"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'"

```
var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient("http://localhost:3000/", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());

var employeeReq = new GraphQLRequest
{
    Query = @"
    query{
        getAllEmployees{employee_id}
    }",
};

var response = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(employeeReq).ConfigureAwait(false);

Console.WriteLine(response);
```

I tried to change the type, but without success.
The GraphQL Server is running on a go backend and there is no problem
when I write the same query in the playground.

Comment: This is often because you didn't get JSON from the response, you got HTML. It is probably an error 500 page or something like that. If you read the HTML it may have a clue what you did wrong.

Comment: This explains why I get < as an exception, probably an HTML tag.
But why is that and what can I do about it?

Comment: Read the HTML. If it is a login page or error page it will have a clue. If the service is your own, then debug the service.